# SmartCardReader won't fire CardAdded method?

Tags: c#, nfc, smartcard-reader

I am trying to get a Microsoft Phone to fire and event, when a NFC tag is tapped. However the method wont fire when tag is tapped.
The cardReader_CardAdded should fire when tag is tapped, but it does nothing. 
Here is the code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        smartCard();
    }

    public async void smartCard()
    {

        string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();
        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
        foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
        {
            SmartCardReader reader = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
            reader.CardAdded += cardReader_CardAdded;
            reader.CardRemoved += cardReader_CardRemoved;
        }
    }
    private void cardReader_CardRemoved(SmartCardReader sender, CardRemovedEventArgs args)
    {

    }
    private async void cardReader_CardAdded(SmartCardReader sender, CardAddedEventArgs args)
    {
        await HandleCard(args.SmartCard);
    }

    private async Task HandleCard(SmartCard card)
    {
        SmartCardProvisioning provisioning = await SmartCardProvisioning.FromSmartCardAsync(card);

        SmartCardStatus status;
        do
        {
            status = await provisioning.SmartCard.GetStatusAsync();
        } while (status == SmartCardStatus.Shared);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I forgot to enable Proximity under Capabilities in the Package.appxmanifest